# Multi-lingual websites with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting, multilingual

When building a multi-lingual website (with ASP.NET web forms), I'll use an HTTP module to rewrite the URLs to end up with something friendly (for humans & search engines) like:

```
uk/products/product_category_one/sub_category_one/index.aspx
uk/products/product_category_one/sub_category_one/widget_mk5.aspx
es/productos/categoría_de_producto_una/widget_mk5.aspx
```

My (newbie) understanding of MVC is that the URL should take the format of

> Controller / Action / Identifier

so replicating the functionality above with MVC will end up with URLs similar to:

```
products/category/123/product_category_one/sub_category_one
products/items/456/widget_mk5
```

Questions..

- Can I insert a country code into the URL before the 'controller' segment?
- Is it possible to map 'products' and 'productos' to the same controller?

Thanks for your help

**Edit:**
In addition to Panos' answer below I found more information on the [ASP.NET Website](http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc/tutorial-05-vb.aspx).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The URL can take almost any other form you like. For more info, check [ASP.NET MVC Framework (Part 2): URL Routing](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/03/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-2-url-routing.aspx). Just for starting (since I am not sure if it is the optimum solution), you can add two new routes in your global.asax:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "ukRoute",
            "{lang}/Products/{action}/{id}/{subcategory}",
            new { lang = "uk", controller = "Products", action = "Index", id = "", subcategory = "" }
        );
        routes.MapRoute(
            "esRoute",
            "{lang}/Productos/{action}/{id}/{subcategory}",
            new { lang = "es", controller = "Products", action = "Index", id = "", subcategory = "" }
        );
```

These routes understand the following URLs (and map both of them to the `ActionResult Category(string id, string subcategory)` method of `ProductsController`):

```
uk/Products/Category/1/A
es/Productos/Category/1/A
```

If you want to create such URLs in your views you can use something like:

```
<%= Html.RouteLink("English 1.A", "ukRoute", new { lang = "uk", action = "Category", id = "1", subcategory = "A" })%>
<%= Html.RouteLink("Spanish 1.A", "esRoute", new { lang = "es", action = "Category", id = "1", subcategory = "A" })%>
```

Comment: does it works? `uk/Products/Category/1/A`  `es/Productos/Category/1/A` In both these scenarios it will be directed to the first Route `ukRoute` since lang is a string field and match.

Comment: I think the method introduced [in this blog](http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2010/01/26/Translating-routes-(ASPNET-MVC-and-Webforms).aspx) is a better idea.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this, but keep in mind that not all countries are languages. For example, en-gb is the usual representation for British English, or more specifically, the Great Britain locale for English content, for example. If you can, it's worth following the RFC1766-derived conventions for language-LOCALE.

Search engines actually tend to do a fairly good job dealing with content-negotiation, by the way, so you need not necessarily have separate URIs for the same content in different languages. Google Japan will crawl with ja-JP as the accept language header, for example.

Comment: Regarding search engines you should emit the "lang" and "dir" attributes on the "html" element.

I prefer the cookie method which can all be dealt with in the Global.asax code (or even wrapped into a parent HttpApplication base class to fully automate for any MVC or ASPX web site) by saving a "culture" cookie at AquireRequestState (with browser or web site default language) which is easy to change to any preference via a "SetLanguage" application method which just changes the cookie and thread culture.

Then the site works without different URLs and the content valid (identifies its language).