# MVC URL Rewrite by using custom field

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a MVC 5 project with model named ProductModel and controller named ProductController.
I also have a Product data row with field Title: Canon DSLR Cameras
By default, when users want to view details product, they will see the url http://../Product/Details/1.

Can we change the url to: http://../Product/Canon-DSLR-Cameras ?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything? With routes maybe?

Comment: I have tried to find solutions with keywords like "MVC URL Rewrite". But they can not resolve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your RouteConfig.cs

You can simple add route map like:

```
routes.MapRoute("Details", "Product/{customUrl}",
       new { controller = "Product", action = "Details" },
       new { customUrl = @"\S+" } );
```

And write a controller action (ProductController.cs):

```
public ActionResult Details(string customUrl)
{
   // find ProductModel by customUrl
   ...
   return View(); // pass the model matching customUrl
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It works for me.  In other case, my site will used in English and Spanish. So, can we change the link to http://../producto/. while continuing use ProductController ?

Comment: @MrStone Please refer answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271769/how-to-localize-the-controller-names-and-actions-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application