# How do I make a ASP.NET MVC application multilingual?

Tags: asp.net, localization, multilingual

How to do the multilingual application in ASp.NET MVC?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291405/multi-lingual-websites-with-asp-net-mvc

Comment: @Marc Gravell: that question addresses only the issue of URL routing

Comment: However here is a question that answers how to localize the application: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192465/how-to-localize-asp-net-mvc-application

Answer (score 5):

See:

[Multiple languages in an ASP.NET MVC application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4034/multiple-languages-in-an-aspnet-mvc-application)

and

[Multi-lingual websites with ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291405/multi-lingual-websites-with-asp-net-mvc)

on this website.

Answer (score 3):

You could do it with resource files

Comment: This shouldn't be voted down because this is the correct answer in short. Read the MVC localization guide and see that local resource files are still the correct way. Because the App_LocalResources and App_GlobalResources are only available at runtime and the new Multilingual App Toolkit is only for Windows Store, there is still no alternative. Hopefully MVC 5 will use the Windows Store method so we have one way of localizing all types of projects and following the international file format standards XLIFF. Until then compiled resources seem to be the only way which satisfies most requirements

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice blog post by Alex Adamyan about ASP.NET MVC 2 localization.

You can view this blog post from here :

http://adamyan.blogspot.com/2010/07/addition-to-aspnet-mvc-localization.html